# Are charisma, dignity and ferocity used for something besides NPC dialogs?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Besides the answers you can give in some dialogs (where I imagine that a kind of "roll check" is performed to see if it succeeds / fails) what are these atributes used for?
Do they unlock special missions or items?

Comment: I've maxed out my charisma (and apparently this reduces dignity and ferocity to zero) but I see no point in it yet

Comment: That's good to know. I asked in chat if they were mutually exclusive, but didn't get an answer.

Comment: Also from the personalities wiki page (http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Personality): "The game keeps track of three aspects of personality: ferocity, dignity, and charm. Certain actions and dialogue choices can affect the personality by increasing one aspect and thereby decreasing the others".

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen that. Last night, when I was wondering about all this, the wiki wasn't working at all.

Comment: It would be great if you maxed one out and were given access to a new skill or trait. But I don't think there is any use for them at all atm.

Answer (score 4):

[Boon Givers](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Boon_Giver) can be convinced to give you a boon for free using a personality speech option.

Comment: And where do I find one of them?

Comment: I know you can find a Swiftness vendor in each of the major cities. I'm not sure about other boons.

Comment: I thought swiftness "vendors" were free in the major cities. For example, in Divinity's Reach the NPCs under the gods statues give this buff just by interacting with them

Comment: Well, maybe I'm thinking of something else then. I ran into one yesterday and charmed them into giving me the buff. It may not have been in a main city, though. Possibly in Beetletun?

Comment: Following the link from your answer, though, has led me into the personalities wiki page, wich states that: "Personality affects gameplay by offering certain dialogue options only to some types and altering the reactions of certain NPCs. For example, barbaric characters might have the option to punch some NPCs, while other NPCs might cower when approached. Several achievements are related to one's personality type. However, the game is designed to avoid extreme consequences, i.e. players are able to take on different personality types without fear of losing out on overall rewards or benefits."

Comment: Yeah, I read that, but I considered that as still falling under conversation options. I can add it to my answer, though, if you'd like.

Comment: Sure. Actually your answer was the kind of extra rewards I was hoping to find out from these personalities

Comment: @stoldark: At the very least, the swiftness vendor I tried talking to in the Black Citadel refused to buff me when I tried selecting the Charm option (which is my highest dialog stat) in the conversation.

Comment: @cloudymusic Approximately what percent of the Charm bar is full?

Comment: @SaintWacko If I recall correctly, slightly above 50%. (It was an almost brand-new character.)

Comment: @cloudymusic Oh, that may be it, then. You may just need a higher Charisma to convince him. My Charisma is nearly full, and I was able to convince a boon giver.

Comment: @SaintWacko: Yeah, it seems pretty clear that that's what it is; just wanted to provide a testimonial to the fact that it *is* possible to have the boon giver reject you.