# How does a character's personality (Chrisma/Dignity/Ferocity) affect the game?

Tags: guild-wars-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are charisma, dignity and ferocity used for something besides NPC dialogs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81923/are-charisma-dignity-and-ferocity-used-for-something-besides-npc-dialogs)

Throughout your character's progress through the game, there are sometimes several different actions you may choose which increase one of the three personality trait. What do these personality traits do? Does it affect a character's personal story line? Does it affect a character's base attributes?

Comment: @yx. I agree this is a duplicate. I must have missed it.

Comment: no biggie, it happens a lot and then the closed question just turns into a guide that points to the original